# Sliding div in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails-3, slidetoggle

I am trying to make a toolbar type section on the top of my site. I just need one div that will be hidden by default, and a button that will be hanging off the bottom of that div. When it is clicked, the div should slide down (with the button still on bottom). And upon clicking, it should slide back up.

Here is what I currently have:

```
<div id="account_toolbar" style="background-color:#fff;">
  <div id="toolbar_contents" style="display:none;">  This is the account toolbar so far
  </div>
  <div id="button" style="background-color: #ff0000;"><%= image_tag    "templates/_global/my_account.png", :id => "my_account_btn", :style => "float: right; margin-right: 100px;" %></div>
</div>
```

The image tag is using ruby/rails syntax, so pay no attention to that. It will render like any other image tag.

Here is the jquery i'm using:

```
$('#my_account_btn').click(function () {
    $('#toolbar_contents').slideToggle();
});
```

So, this is actually working for the most part. My problem however is that the spacing where the toolbar content div goes, pushes the account button down. When it slides up or down it temporarily attaches itself to the bottom of the div, then jumps back down once it is finished sliding (leaving a gap between the bottom of the hidden div and the top of the account button).

I hope that makes sense.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you guys gave me some ideas, thanks!

What ended up fixing it was setting the bottom div (the one holding the image/button) to the height of the button. Before, the div was not displaying and had a final height of 0px in the browser.

```
<div id="account_toolbar" style="background-color:#fff;">
  <div id="toolbar_contents" style="">  This is the account toolbar so far
  </div>
  <div id="button" style="background-color: #ff0000; height:59px;"><%= image_tag "templates/_global/my_account.png", :id => "my_account_btn", :style => "float: right; margin-right: 100px;" %></div>
</div>
```

The style background color of red was not showing at all before. I had that there temporarily to see where the divs were showing up.

Anyway, thanks again guys!

Answer (score 1):

This is because you dont specify the width of some of your elements and you can apply floating in order for it to be intact. Try to get this idea.

```
<style>
#account_toolbar{
    width:500px;
}
.toolbar_contents_wrapper{
    float:left;
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
}
#button{
    float:left;
    width:300px;
}

.clear{
    clear:both;
}
 </style>


 <div id="account_toolbar" style="background-color:#fff;">
    <div class="toolbar_contents_wrapper">
     <div id="toolbar_contents" style="display:none;">  This is the account toolbar so far
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="button" style="background-color: #ff0000;"><img    src="#" id="my_account_btn" style="float: right; margin-right: 100px;" /></div>
</div>


<script>
$(function(){
    $('#my_account_btn').click(function () {
    $('#toolbar_contents').slideToggle();
});
});
</script>
```

Notice the .toolbar_contents_wrapper this would prevent your button below to move up/down. I tested this code and it works.

Comment: I need the button to be directly below the toolbar_contents div, not to the right. I tried adding 100 percent widths on the divs, and it did not fix anything. thanks for the reply.

Comment: I updated the code in order for the button not to move up/down. I have tested it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `display:none` and instead on your document load run a .hide() instead. Below is code that works on my site.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#toolbar_contents').hide();
  $('#my_account_btn').click(function() {
    $('#toolbar_contents').slideToggle(400);
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: this does the same thing unfortunately. I probably didn't explain very well, but the top div has toolbar contents that should be hidden. The bottom div is just to hold the button. There is probably a better way to do that.. I just can't think of one. Thanks for the help!